# C# How to loop through the list and add string into the list?

Tags: c#, list, xamarin

this is my first time posting a question here. May I know how to loop through the list and add string into the list?

this is my code and it failed in the unit test.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ItemTracker
{
    public class Book: Item
    {
        private List<string> _authors;
        private string _title;
        private int _yearPublished; 

        public Book(string id, double price, Category category, List<string> authors, string title, int 
                   yearPublished):base(id, price, category)
        {
            _authors = new List<string>();
            _authors = authors;
            foreach (string a in _authors)
            {
                _authors.Add(a);
            }
            _title = title;
            _yearPublished = yearPublished;
        }

        public List<string> Authors
        {
            get {return _authors;}
            set { _authors = value;}
        }

        public override string View() 
        {
            return "Author:" + _authors + "\nTitle:" + _title + "\nYear Published:" + _yearPublished;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my unit test for it:

```
    [Test()]
    public void TestBook() 
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("J.K. Rowling");
        Book book = new Book("B1001", 39.9, Category.Book, a,"Harry Potter", 1997);
        Assert.IsTrue(book.View() == "Author: J.K. Rowling" + "\nTitle: Harry Potter" + "\nYear 
               Published: 1997");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that loop will ever work. Surely if you are looping through `_authors` and it has at least one item in the list, it will infinitely loop and thrown a stack overflow exception. Personally I would just have another list and add it to that other list.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly? Adding items to a list you're iterating over is probably not the best way to do what you want to do anyways.

Comment: You can use ```_authors.ToList()``` to create a copy and iterate over that one instead.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `_authors = authors`? Doesn't that accomplish what you want to do?

Comment: `_authors = new List<string>(authors);` creates a new list with the items of your authors parameter

Comment: When you first do `_authors = new List<string>();` and immediately `_authors = authors;` , then that new List you created is ignored and left for the garbage collector to clean up. That first line does *not* "initialize" the list to have it "filled" by the second line. Instead that second line just replaces the value assigned in the first.

Answer (score 4):

You're printing the object name `List<string>` and not the name(s) of the `authors`. That is one of the reasons your unit test is failing. Try this instead.

```
    public override string View() 
    {
        var allAuthors = string.Join( " ", _authors );
        return "Author: " + allAuthors + "\nTitle: " + _title + "\nYear Published: " + _yearPublished;
    }
```

As others have also noted, you should remove that loop from your `ctor` and just use:

```
_authors = authors;
```

Or, if you want a copy:

```
_authors = new List<string>( authors );
```

No need to loop.. This should also stop you from getting an `InvalidOperationException` since you're modifying your `List<string>` while `iterating` through it.

Also, you're doing a direct comparison of the string which is brittle. If you add an extra space somewhere the `string` comparison will fail..

Answer (score 1):

Regarding constructor. 
If you want to loop through authors parameter and add every entry to
_authors private list just delete `_authors = authors;`
and loop through `authors` not `_authors`.
Like this:

```
public Book(string id, double price, Category category, List<string> authors, string title, int yearPublished) : base(id, price, category)
        {
            _authors = new List<string>();
            foreach (string a in authors)
            {
                _authors.Add(a);
            }
            _title = title;
            _yearPublished = yearPublished;
        }
```

Additionally the `View()` method doesn't return the string you expect it to return.
It just uses the `ToString()` method derived from `object` class.
So you need to explicitly loop through `_authors` list and build the string first:

```
        public override string View() 
        {
            string authorString = "";
            foreach(var a in _authors)
            {
               authorString += $"{a} ";
            }
            return "Author:" + authorString + "\nTitle:" + _title + "\nYear Published:" + _yearPublished;
        }
```

or build your own `Authors` class with `ToString()` implemented your way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Does my unit test have any error in it?

Comment: It is a tricky question as tests are the expression of the software requirements which are unknown here :)

Comment: Sorry to bother @George, I tried but still fail in my unit test. Below is my unit test, is there any error in it?                                                                             
        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("J.K. Rowling");
        Book book = new Book("B1001", 39.9, Category.Book, a,"Harry Potter", 1997);
        Assert.IsTrue(book.View() == "Author: J.K. Rowling" + "\nTitle: Harry Potter" + "\nYearPublished: 1997")

Comment: I don't know if you changed your book.View() code or not. First suspicion is the space after "Author:" and before "J.K. Rowling".